# How to find unsorted fragments of data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

Let's assume that I've got a `data.frame` that is supposed to be sorted with respect to selected columns and I want to make sure that it is indeed a case. I could try something like:

```
library(dplyr)
mpg2 <- mpg %>% 
  arrange(manufacturer, model, year)
identical(mpg, mpg2)
[1] FALSE
```

but if the `identical` returns `FALSE` this only lets me know that a dataset is in incorrect order.

1. What if I would like to inspect only those rows that are in fact in incorrect order? How can I filter those out of the whole dataset? (I need to avoid looping here at best, as the dataset I work with is pretty large)
2. If the remaining variables (not used for ordering) are different for the same value of `manufacturer`, `model`, `year`, how `dplyr::arrange` decides which observation comes first? Does it preserve the order from original dataset (`mpg` here)?

Comment: Using `all.equal` and its variations gives some info on how they differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As for the second question**, I believe that `dplyr::arrange` is *stable*, it preserves the order of the rows when there are ties in the sorting columns.
This can be seen by comparing with the result from `base::order`. From the help page, section `Details` (my emphasis):

> In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are
>   used to break the ties. If the values are still tied, values in the
>   later arguments are used to break the tie (see the first example).
>   **The sort used is stable (except for method = "quick"), so any
>
>   unresolved ties will be left in their original ordering.**

```
mpg2 <- mpg %>% 
  arrange(manufacturer, model, year)

i <- with(mpg, order(manufacturer, model, year))
mpg3 <- mpg[i, ]

identical(as.data.frame(mpg2), as.data.frame(mpg3))
#[1] TRUE
```

The values are identical, except for their classes. So `dplyr::arrange` does preserve the order in the case of ties.

**As for the first question**, maybe the code below answers it. It just gets the rows for which the next order number is smaller than the previous one. This means that those rows have changed relative positions.

```
j <- which(diff(i) < 0)
mpg[i[j], ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something I've needed before. Usually it's best practice to not rely on table ordering. Only times I would rely on it, the ordering would be contained within a function ie I wouldn't have function B depend on ordering that happens in function A.

I think this does what you ask for, using the `data.table` package. You set keys with this package, and they are ordered from left to right in terms of primary, secondary key etc. I'm not sure if concatenating the keys together is the best way, but its simple.

```
# reproducible fake data
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a=rep(1:5, 2), b=letters[1:10], c=sample(1:3, 10, TRUE))

# scramble
dt <- dt[sample(1:.N)]

# make the ideal structure
keys <- c("a", "b")
dt_ideal <- copy(dt)
dt_ideal <- setkeyv(dt_ideal, keys)
key(dt_ideal)

# function to find keys not the same for each row. Pasting together
findBad <- function(dt, dt_ideal){
  not_ok <- which(dt_ideal[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=">")), .SDcols=keys] != 
                    dt[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=">")), .SDcols=keys])
  not_ok
}

# index of bad rows - all bad in this case
not_ok <- findBad(dt, dt_ideal)
dt[not_ok]

# better eg, swap 7 & 8
dt2 <- copy(dt_ideal)
dt2 <- dt2[c(1:6, 8, 7, 9:10)]
not_ok <- findBad(dt2, dt_ideal)
dt2[not_ok]
```